# Extjs 4 Grid autoScroll

Tags: extjs4

I am using `Ext.grid.GridPanel` in Extjs 4.

Autoscroll is not working in my `GridPanel`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't think we can guess what code you have, so we are unlikely to know how to fix your bug.

Comment: autoScroll:true (scrollbars) is not working, auto scrolling to a focused record is not working, or scroll to a selected row using mind control is not working? :p

Answer (score 14):

Put below config in your parent container of GridPanel.

```
   layout: 'fit'
```

And remove `autoScroll` from `GridPanel`.

Comment: I have been spinning my wheels on this all day. Thank you!

Comment: the issue is/was the autoScroll option sets overflow to auto, but no height is specified. So you either have to set a height to the container/grid or pick a parent layout that sets the height for you. In most cases the `layout: 'fit'` is most suited. +1 for @Kunal

Comment: Had the same problem with version 6.1 and that trick fixed it perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

```
scroll: true,
  viewConfig: {
    style: {
      overflow: 'auto',
        overflowX: 'hidden'
    }
  },
```

Try the above config option. This also will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent container needs to use some other layout other than 'fit', as suggested by previous comments, you could try this: set the height of the grid once the store loads. Moreover, instead of having to calculate the actual height, this may do the trick:

```
grid.setHeight('100%')
```

According to documentation, setHeight can accept "[A String used to set the CSS height style.](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-setHeight)"