# Scrollable Attributes Grid Container - extJS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am working on making a container in extJS that will dynamically add Attribute Grids depending on the user clicking a row on another grid within my form. I would like for this container which is housing the Attribute 
Grids to be scrollable so that the container would remain a fixed size, but the user can add or remove as many attribute grids inside as they'd like.

Here is a snippet of my code that I am using to create my container:

```
Ext.define('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefAttributeGridContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    width: 400,
    border: 1,
    style: {borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
    defaults: {
        labelWidth: 80,
        // implicitly create Container by specifying xtype
        xtype: 'datefield',
        flex: 1,
        style: {
            padding: '10px'
        }
    },
    items: [
        Ext.create('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefRunListAttributesGrid'),
        Ext.create('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefRunListAttributesGrid'),
        Ext.create('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefRunListAttributesGrid'),
        Ext.create('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefRunListAttributesGrid'),
        Ext.create('SSAF.plugin.CHEF.view.chefRunListAttributesGrid')
    ]
});
```

Although I have added the autoScroll attribute to my grid, I am not receiving the intended effect.

Here is how it currently looks:

[image: Attributes Container]

I would like it to remain a fixed size just like all of my other components within my layout:

[image: Layout Boxes]

Any idea as to what I may be missing in order to achieve my desire effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the solution offered by this post:

[Grid AutoScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835618/extjs-4-grid-autoscroll)